# Function that takes any queryset and a string and that does operation on queryset.string

Tags: django

it's probably more of a python object programming problem but I'm not sure.

I have tried to create the tupling_object function below but adding a string parameter "country_name" in the case of the countries object but it didn't work. The first functions are working fine but I would like to generalize it.

```
countries = country.objects.all()
categories = category.objects.all()
sectors = sector.objects.all()
def tupling_countries(countries):
    list = [('','')]
    for country in countries:
        list.append((country.country_name, country.country_name))
    return list
def tupling_categories(categories):
    list = [('','')]
    for category in categories:
        list.append((category.category_name, category.category_name))
    return list
def tupling_sectors(sectors):
    list = [('','')]
    for sector in sectors:
        list.append((sector.sector_name, sector.sector_name))
    return list

#here's what I would like to do
def tupling_object(objects):
    list = [('','')]
    for object in objects:
        list.append((object.something ,object.something ))
    return list
# 

COUNTRY_CHOICES = tupling_countries(countries)
CATEGORY_CHOICES = tupling_categories(categories)
SECTOR_CHOICES = tupling_sectors(sectors)
country = forms.CharField(label='Select a country', widget=forms.Select(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES))
category = forms.CharField(label='Select a category of activities', widget=forms.Select(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES))
sector = forms.CharField(label='Select a sector', widget=forms.Select(choices=SECTOR_CHOICES))
```

Also is there a better way to create dropdown form than tupling my data like that.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this in the wrong way. There is a way to directly create choices from querysets, which is to use ModelChoiceField. So replace your entire code with:

```
country = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Select a country', queryset=country.objects.all())
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Select a category of activities', queryset=category.objects.all())
sector = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Select a sector', queryset=sector.objects.all())
```

Comment: Hello, it seems a way better option indeed, but it returns country object("name of the country") instead of just "name of the country. How can I change it?

Comment: You need to define `__str__` methods on your models.

Comment: Was wondering why everyone was defining __str__ XD. It's fully working thanks.